# Qt applications don't work due to libEGL

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie, qt, shared-libraries

I am developing some (simple) GUI applications for the RPi2 in Qt5.
The setup:
The code development is performed on a Windows laptop using Netbeans + Qt Designer and remotely built on the RPi running Raspbian Jessie with tools that come with it (g++ 4.9.2, Qt 5.3.2, package qt5-default), as [described here](http://www.raspberry-projects.com/pi/programming-in-c/compilers-and-ides/netbeans-windows/installing-netbeans-for-c-remote-development-on-a-raspberry-pi). This setup generaly works just fine.

However, even  a [minimal example](https://netbeans.org/kb/74/cnd/qt-applications.html) doesn't work, although builds ok. It fails to start, and `libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate` appears if the application has been started from the terminal.

Can't Qt run on the RPi? Otherwise please help me resolve this problem.

EDIT1: 
Here what I have after do performing `find`command like Alexey Vesnin suggested:

```
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so.1
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so.1.0.0
/usr/lib/chromium-browser/libs/libEGL.so
/usr/lib/chromium-browser/libs/libEGL.so.TOC
/opt/vc/lib/libEGL.so
/opt/vc/lib/libEGL_static.a


/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libGLESv2.so.2
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libGLESv2.so.2.0.0
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libGLESv2.so
/usr/lib/chromium-browser/libs/libGLESv2.so
/usr/lib/chromium-browser/libs/libGLESv2.so.TOC
/opt/vc/lib/libGLESv2_static.a
/opt/vc/lib/libGLESv2.so
```

EDIT2: The list with additional information:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 171312 Nov 11 14:20 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so.1.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 107880 Nov  2 22:27 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/libs/libEGL.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 14189 Nov  2 22:27 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/libs/libEGL.so.TOC
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 202072 Dec 19 21:01 /opt/vc/lib/libEGL.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 245356 Dec 19 21:19 /opt/vc/lib/libEGL_static.a



-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 29996 Jan 12  2016 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libGLESv2.so.2.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2632816 Nov  2 22:27 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/libs/libGLESv2.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 29617 Nov  2 22:27 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/libs/libGLESv2.so.TOC
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 100008 Dec 19 21:19 /opt/vc/lib/libGLESv2_static.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 105768 Nov 25 17:35 /opt/vc/lib/libGLESv2.so
```

EDIT3:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x7ecef000)
    /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so (0x76f53000)
    libQt5Widgets.so.5 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0x76a25000)
    libQt5Gui.so.5 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x76655000)
    libQt5Core.so.5 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x761d0000)
    libGLESv2.so => /opt/vc/lib/libGLESv2.so (0x761ab000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0 (0x76183000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6 (0x760a6000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.6 (0x7602b000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x75ffe000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 (0x75ebd000)
    libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x75e63000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x75d5f000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libX11.so.6 (0x75c49000)
    libGLESv2.so.2 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libGLESv2.so.2 (0x75c31000)
    /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0x54b67000)
    libpng12.so.0 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpng12.so.0 (0x75c01000)
    libharfbuzz.so.0 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x75ba5000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libz.so.1 (0x75b7d000)
    libicui18n.so.52 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libicui18n.so.52 (0x759bd000)
    libicuuc.so.52 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libicuuc.so.52 (0x75874000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl.so.2 (0x75861000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/librt.so.1 (0x7584a000)
    libEGL.so => /opt/vc/lib/libEGL.so (0x75810000)
    libbcm_host.so => /opt/vc/lib/libbcm_host.so (0x757ea000)
    libvchiq_arm.so => /opt/vc/lib/libvchiq_arm.so (0x757d4000)
    libvcos.so => /opt/vc/lib/libvcos.so (0x757ba000)
    libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libffi.so.6 (0x757aa000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpcre.so.3 (0x75736000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libxcb.so.1 (0x75717000)
    libdrm.so.2 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdrm.so.2 (0x756fa000)
    libglapi.so.0 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libglapi.so.0 (0x756c1000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libfreetype.so.6 (0x75629000)
    libgraphite2.so.3 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgraphite2.so.3 (0x755fb000)
    libicudata.so.52 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libicudata.so.52 (0x73f7e000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libXau.so.6 (0x73f73000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x73f67000)
```

Comment: Are you trying to run the application remotely?

Comment: no, I run it from the RPi

Comment: @goldilocks in case of remote running an error messages would be different

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a usual linux and Unix problem, nothing Pi-related. Here is the problem: your libs need to be symlinked. Do `sudo -s` and become a root for such an operation. And let's troubleshoot it!

First, find them, like this:

```
# find / -name libEGL* -type f
# find / -name libGLESv2* -type f
```

and do this linking to the **full paths to files** like this:

```
# ln -fs /path/to/lib/libEGL.so /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so
# ln -fs /path/to/lib/libEGL.so /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so.1
# ln -fs /path/to/lib/libGLESv2.so /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libGLESv2.so
# ln -fs /path/to/lib/libGLESv2.so /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libGLESv2.so.2
```

and let the OS know what you have done and take it into account like this:

```
# ldconfig
```

The `/path/to/lib` part you should replace with full path that `find` commands will show you.
And if running from unprivileged user - make sure that it's in `video` group - sometimes this old part of permission settings does float up. How to check:

```
# getent group video | cut -d: -f3
```

if it gives nothing - then it's not that case, but if it gives a number, then type your username in `groups` command - an example for user `pi`:

```
# groups pi
```

if it does not shows `video` group - add it *as a supplementary group*, not as the main one, like this:

```
# usermod -a -G video pi
```

this will add user `pi` to group `video` without breaking things up

UPDATE: additional check command to find out what are the files found:

```
# find / -name libEGL* -type f -exec ls -la {} \;
# find / -name libGLESv2* -type f -exec ls -la {} \;
```

UPDATE#2: Try to do this from root:

```
# ln -fs /opt/vc/lib/libEGL.so /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so
# ln -fs /opt/vc/lib/libGLESv2.so /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libGLESv2.so
# ldconfig
```

UPDATE#3: building Qt5 with bugfixes from source.

- go [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-requirements.html), install dependencies via apt-get (the -dev packages)
- as root do `apt-get build-dep qt5-default`
- as root do `apt-get install libxcb-xinerama0-dev flex bison gperf libicu-dev libxslt-dev ruby libssl-dev libxcursor-dev libxcomposite-dev libxdamage-dev libxrandr-dev libdbus-1-dev libfontconfig1-dev libcap-dev libxtst-dev libpulse-dev libudev-dev libpci-dev libnss3-dev libasound2-dev libxss-dev libegl1-mesa-dev gperf bison libasound2-dev libgstreamer0.10-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev`, after that `apt-get install '^libxcb.*-dev' libx11-xcb-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libxrender-dev libxi-dev`

after that do this:

```
 # git clone https://code.qt.io/qt/qt5.git
 # cd qt5
 # git submodule update --init
```

after that link `./configure --help` output for your case and we will continue

FINAL UPDATE: source build did the trick, the problem was with an outdated Qt in packages. The configuration string :

```
 # mkdir qt-build
 # cd qt-build
 # ../configure -opensource -static -confirm-license -release -nomake examples -openssl-runtime -prefix /usr
```

Raspberry Pi build took around 40 hours and 6+Gb of storage space. Problem fixed

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52616/discussion-on-answer-by-alexey-vesnin-qt-applications-dont-work-due-to-libegl).

Comment: around 46 hours to be more precise

Comment: but the victory is ours, finally!

Comment: I want to upvote this - but after 2 years, there's no excuse for the package maintainers to have still not fixed this :(

Comment: @UKMonkey not just this matter has forced me to make a Linux distro of my own flavor - the problem still multiplies :(

Comment: @AlexeyVesnin hello. When I run the commands to find libEGL, I only get these two:

1) /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/mesa-egl/libEGL.so.1.0.0

and

2) /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/mesa-egl/libGLESv2.so.2.0.0

When I try to run sudo qtcreator, it tells me its an unknown command. Should I install this first?

Comment: compile it first - as we did

Answer (score 2):

In my case this fixed the issue

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libGLESv2.so.2 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libGLESv2.so
```

Comment: I think you're barking up the wrong tree looking at Qt.  I just got that error trying to run mpv on a Pi.   ldd says it doesn't use Qt at all.  And I have a few version symlinks like the above.  It's some kind of permission error involving DRI, almost like an xhost thing.