# Installing MPV with FFmpeg + MMAL: Could not create EGL surface!

Tags: raspbian, video, raspbian-stretch, ffmpeg

I would like to build mpv from source for the raspberry pi. This is turning out to be quite difficult.

## Error

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ./mpv-build/mpv/build/mpv --hwdec=mmal --vo=rpi --log-file=~/mpv.log small.mp4 
Playing: small.mp4
 (+) Video --vid=1 (*) (h264 560x320 30.000fps)
 (+) Audio --aid=1 --alang=eng (*) (aac 1ch 48000Hz)
Using hardware decoding (mmal).
VO: [rpi] 560x320 mmal
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
[vo/rpi] Could not create EGL surface!
[vo/rpi] EGL/GLES initialization for OSD renderer failed.
Could not initialize video chain.
Video: no video
[ao/oss] Can't open audio device /dev/dsp: No such file or directory
[ao] Failed to initialize audio driver 'oss'
Could not open/initialize audio device -> no sound.
Audio: no audio


Exiting... (Errors when loading file)
```

## Setup & Procedure

OS: Raspbian Stretch 2018-06-27

Hardware: Raspberry Pi 3B/3B+

```
sudo apt-get update -y 
sudo apt-get upgrade -y 
sudo rpi-update
```

in raspi-config, go to advanced > memory split: 256

reboot now

```
sudo apt-get install -y gperf bison flex autoconf automake make texinfo help2man libtool libtool-bin ncurses-dev git yasm mercurial cmake cmake-curses-gui libfribidi-dev checkinstall libfontconfig1-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libgles2-mesa-dev gnutls-dev libsmbclient-dev libpulse-dev libbluray-dev libdvdread-dev libluajit-5.1-dev libjpeg-dev libv4l-dev libcdio-cdda-dev libcdio-paranoia-dev libmp3lame-dev libx264-dev 

git clone https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv-build.git
cd mpv-build

export LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/vc/lib
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/vc/lib/pkgconfig/
export CPATH=/opt/vc/include
# export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/vc/lib"

echo "--enable-libx264
--enable-omx-rpi
--enable-libmp3lame
--enable-mmal
--enable-gpl
--enable-nonfree
--disable-v4l2-m2m" > ffmpeg_options

echo "--enable-rpi
" > mpv_options

./update
./rebuild -j4
sudo scripts/mpv-install
```

## Things I've tried

1. Links like this

   `sudo ln -s libbrcmEGL.so libEGL.so
   sudo ln -s libbrcmGLESv2.so libGLESv2.so`
2. Links like this, ([source](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/61078/qt-applications-dont-work-due-to-libegl))

   `sudo ln -fs /opt/vc/lib/libEGL.so /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so
   sudo ln -fs /opt/vc/lib/libGLESv2.so /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libGLESv2.so
   sudo ldconfig`

Neither worked, so then I rebooted and did some more searching. I found some posts saying it was an opengl problem so I tried to install new opengl packages

`sudo apt-get install -y libglu1-mesa-dev freeglut3-dev mesa-common-dev`

That didn't work, so I thought maybe it couldn't find packages I already had installed. I tried exporting the variables that were used in the install

`export LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/vc/lib
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/vc/lib/pkgconfig/
export CPATH=/opt/vc/include`

still nope.

Next I found a guide saying there needed to be an rpi-update. I had run one at the beginning, but I decided to try again.

`sudo rpi-update`

no luck!

Found another post that led to this

- [git post linking solution](https://github.com/tipam/pi3d/issues/177#issuecomment-108175834)
- [post with solution](https://pi3d.github.io/html/FAQ.html)

`sudo ln -fs /opt/vc/lib/libEGL.so /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so
sudo ln -fs /opt/vc/lib/libEGL.so /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so.1
sudo ln -fs /opt/vc/lib/libGLESv2.so /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libGLESv2.so
sudo ln -fs /opt/vc/lib/libGLESv2.so /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libGLESv2.so.2`

After this point desperation and frustration sink in and further attempts go undocumented. Needless to say, nothing I tried worked, which leads me to post here

Comment: why not `sudo apt install mpv`?

Comment: It doesn't really work for rpi. It needs FFmpeg to be installed with hardware acceleration (the mmal in title) or it's basically unusable, like 1 frame per second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an RPi3B+
I just installed **mpv** and **ffmpeg** 3.4.1 by following this well-written tutorial:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=199775

It worked. I suggest you follow the tutorial to the letter. If it says "reboot", then do that. Don't think "Oh not necessary yet."

Actually, I only wanted to update **ffmpeg**, but in the end I achieved my goal (updated **ffmpeg**), but I am also *very* impressed with the performance of **mpv** now that it is using the Rpi's hardware acceleration.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi and welcome. It would be better if you edited and included the process and any code, from the link, in your answer. As it stands this is a bit of a [*link only*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) answer. If the link dies then your answer will not be of much use to anyone, unfortunately.

Comment: Awesome, this worked for me. It's unfortunate the mpv-build tools don't work directly

Answer (score 0):

> "In normal circumstances there is NEVER a need to run rpi-update as it always gets you to the leading edge firmware and kernel and because that may be a testing version it could leave your RPi unbootable". https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=916911#p916911
>   Even the [rpi-update](https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-update) documentation now warns "Even on Raspbian you should only use this with a good reason. This gets you the latest bleeding edge kernel/firmware."

`sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install --reinstall raspberrypi-bootloader raspberrypi-kernel`
will put it back to the latest supported kernel/bootcode.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this. The reason I ran rpi update is that several times it came up from other posters that it may be required for mpv compilation. Here are a few examples from a forum [post 1](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=199775&start=25#p1261385), [post 2](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=199775&start=25#p1265729)

Comment: Reverting did not change the error message