# (Error trying to run qjackctl) libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate qt5ct: using qt5ct plugin

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, pi-3b+, qt, opengles

Running Raspbian installed with NOOBS. `qjackctl` is installed with all its dependencies using Synaptic. Just trying to run `Guitarix` on my Pi3 B+. I tried following the instructions in [this solution](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/61078/qt-applications-dont-work-due-to-libegl), but the `../configure...` command at the end just returned an error about missing directories. Help is appreciated, this is my first time using a Pi or Linux.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Qt applications don't work due to libEGL](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/61078/qt-applications-dont-work-due-to-libegl)

Comment: @Dirk That is what the OP followed but doesn't work :)

Comment: Welcome to the Raspberry Pi flavoured corner of the Stack Exchange network - you may wish to take the [tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) which may help you to ask questions that furnish good replies.

Comment: There's not enough information provided here to answer your question - or really to understand fully what your question is.  We'll need, for example, the specific errors that you got.  Maybe more.

Comment: And while you're at it, check if the directory in question is really missing or not accessible to the build script.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=971944 and from my own coding experience (I code for a macOs/Windows/Linux project that makes use of the Qt Libs) the RPi's OpenGLES is the embedded form which is not the same as a full Desktop system OpenGL - and some OpenGL stuff does not work on it (sadly that includes the oldest simplest *direct* OpenGL 1.0 stuff that is exactly what the project I code for uses).

I tried to build this on my RPi and after cloning the Guitarix project (from my `~/src/ directory`): `git clone http://git.code.sf.net/p/guitarix/git ./guitarix` and after changing to the `~/src/guitarix/trunk/` directory and failing to run the command: `./waf --configure` through to successful completion, I needed to work my way through finding and installing needed things - though you should be able to do all the package installation steps (with other associated pacakages) at one swell foop:

- create a symbolic link from gcc/g++ to gcc-6/g++-6: `sudo ln -s -i /usr/bin/gcc-6 /usr/bin/gcc` and `sudo ln -s -i /usr/bin/g++-6 /usr/bin/g++`
- install intltool and gettext-devel packages: `sudo apt-get install intltool gettext-devel`
- install sndfile containing package: `sudo apt-get install libsndfile-dev`
- install gthread containing package: `sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev`
- install glibmm-2.4 containing package: `sudo apt-get install libgmm-2.4`
- install header fftw3.f containing package: `sudo apt-get install libfftw3-dev`
- install libcurl containing package: `sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev` {note this virtual package could also be provided by: `libcurl4-openssl-dev` or `libcurl4-nss-dev` but since I already had `libcurl3` I suspected the later version (and its development headers) would be the most straightforward to use}
- install jack >= 1.9.2 containing package: `sudo apt get install libjack-jackd2-dev` {note this installs the jack 1.9.10 version currently}
- install gkt+-2.0 >= 2.20 containing package: `libgtk2.0-dev libpango1.0-dev libcairo2-dev`

Unfortunately I hit a - hopefully temporary - blockage in that the RPi is currently using `libcairo2` and `libcairo-gobject2` at version **1.14.8-1+rpi** (i.e. an Raspberry Pi special compilation of those two - the unmodified versions are also available as **1.14.8-1**) however libcairo2 is only listed as a version **1.14.8-1** and it only accepts the other libcairo packages **without** the suffix.  I have found this Raspberry Pi forum article about it: "[Unable to install libgtk2.0-dev on Raspberry Pi 2](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=123947&p=1406247)" and I have reported my findings and my suspicions that we need a libcairo2-dev version **1.14.8-1+rpi** with a dependency on the other suffixed packages.

~That is all I can find out at the moment - I hope I can update this when this issue is sorted...~

Update:
Seems that in the past I experimented with a different repository and have got some problems to sort out in that- given that I am away from home (and my RPi) for a few days I cannot do anything until I get back.