# libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

I'm developing an application using `qt5.11` on Raspberry Pi 3. My code works on my laptop with ubuntu 18.xx. When I put my code on the RPi, I can compile it with the Makefile (`make -j2`) but when I want to launch my program I get the following message:

```
16:02:44: Starting /home/pi/build-VideoProcessor-Desktop-Debug/VideoProcessor...
**libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate**
**qt5ct: using qt5ct plugin**

(VideoProcessor:985): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 16:02:55.208: cannot register existing type 'GtkWidget'
(VideoProcessor:985): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 16:02:55.208: g_type_add_interface_static: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_INSTANTIATABLE (instance_type)' failed
(VideoProcessor:985): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 16:02:55.208: cannot register existing type 'GtkBuildable'
(VideoProcessor:985): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 16:02:55.208: g_type_interface_add_prerequisite: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_INTERFACE (interface_type)' failed
(VideoProcessor:985): GLib-CRITICAL **: 16:02:55.208: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed
(VideoProcessor:985): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 16:02:55.208: g_type_add_interface_static: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_INSTANTIATABLE (instance_type)' failed
(VideoProcessor:985): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 16:02:55.208: g_type_register_static: assertion 'parent_type > 0' failed
```

I don't understand what's going on with my RPi because my code works with my laptop.

Somebody could help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try removing xserver-xorg-video-fbturbo, it causes this behavior as well as other problems:

```
sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-video-fbturbo
sudo reboot
```

[update 2021-04-21]
The problem returned even with xserver-xorg-video-fbturbo removed.
This post has another solution which works:  [Qt applications don't work due to libEGL](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/61078/qt-applications-dont-work-due-to-libegl)

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libGLESv2.so.2 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libGLESv2.so
```

Comment: do not do this! removes the desktop.